# start-mining with monerod doesn't seem to turn on mining

Tags: monerod, cpu-mining, mining, linux

When i start monerod with

> monerod --start-mining [MY_WALLET_ADDRESS] --mining-threads 1 --bg-mining-enable --bg-mining-ignore-battery --detach

I get :

```
global  src/daemon/main.cpp:279 Monero 'Helium Hydra' (v0.11.1.0-release)
Forking to background...
```

Suggesting that the daemon and mining have started. However when I do:

> monerod --status

I see:

```
Height: 1455991/1461539 (99.6%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 283.02 MH/s, v6, up to date, 8(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 2m 34s
```

This suggests it is **not mining** . What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can start mining until fully synced.

Start monerod without the --start_mining, and just start it once it syncs.

show_hr / hide_gr in monerod will show / hide your mining hashrate.

Comment: But it is not always fully in sync.. I run a full node with monerod always running and connected to net (despite an interruption here and there) so it goes in and out of sync (between 100% and 99% say)... However given the above command would monerod not automatically start mining when in sync?  Also how do I send monerod  show_hr when it is running in background ?